# jQuery, Ajax Request, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Wondering how I can get if the value of a checkbox if it's checked then I want it be stored in a PHP session if possible.

Not sure this can be done. Hence the question on here!

Here's a small/important part of the code I have.

```
      <div class="accessories-right">
         <h3><?php echo $row['title'] ;?></h3>
         <p><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p>
         <div style="width: 700px; float: left; min-height: 20px;">
             <div id="ck-button">
                 <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" value="1" style="visibility: hidden;" name="checked" class="box" id="box"><span>SELECT</span>
                 </label>
             </div>
             <div class="accessories-text"><?php echo $row['price']; ?></div>
         </div>
     </div>
        <div style="margin: 20px 0px 40px 0px; padding:0; clear: both;"></div>


    <div style="float: left; margin: 3px 0px 0px 760px;">
        <button class="green-btn" id="more">Continue &raquo;</button>
    </div>
```

The button has an ID and I have tried something like stated below: But I need it to be on the same page and store in a session to use later.

```
 $(".success").hide();
        $(".error").hide();

        $("#more").click(function() {
            var checked = $("#box").val();
            var dataString = 'checked='+ checked;

            if(checked == '')
            {
               $(".success").hide();
               $(".error").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "accessories_post.php",
                    data: checked,
                    success: function() {
                        $(".success").show();
                        $(".error").hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

But this isn't really doing what I want it to do.

---

Sorry I also forgot to add that I'm wanting to like select multiple items then add them to a mail() function to email this info off to the client.

[image]

So i'd like to select either or of these items then have it sent to the client via email

Comment: You can send an ajax request if the checkbox is checked,Ajax call will invoke the PHP file which will set session value for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your `ajax()` call as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "accessories_post.php",
    data: {checked: checked},    // Take note of this line.
    success: function() {
        $(".success").show();
        $(".error").hide();
    }
});
```

This changes the `data` parameter to an object, whose `checked` property will be either `true` or `false` (the value of the variable `checked`. The reason it's done this way is because if you just set `data` to `true` or `false`, there's no effect. `POST` data needs to be sent as a set of key / value pairs.

On the PHP side, you can then evaluate whether or not the checkbox is checked with this code:

```
$isChecked = (isset($_POST["checked"])) ? (bool)$_POST["checked"] : false;
```

Comment: Ok that's cool that gives me a better understanding I guess, so let me do some messing around with it and i'll update later.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try This....
    $(".success").hide();
    $(".error").hide();

    $("#more").click(function() {
       var checked='';
       if($('#box').is(':checked')){
          checked=$('#box').val();
       }
        var dataString = 'checked='+ checked;

        if(checked == '')
        {
           $(".success").hide();
           $(".error").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "accessories_post.php",
                data: checked,
                success: function() {
                    $(".success").show();
                    $(".error").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

   And in your accessories_post.php set this posted value to session like this

   $_SESSION['anyname']=$_POST['checked']
```